# Error 2032 while loading Flex 4 application using VPN connection

Tags: apache-flex, cross-domain, vpn, framework-caching

I am facing an issue in one of the flex 4 applications. When trying to access the application using a vpn connection it is not loading. It shows error 2032. The application uses framework caching. The framework file was not loaded at all. The download progress bar was in 0% status.
But the application works fine if not in vpn.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

I got the same issue when i was testing in my local server. There I replaced the swf from the bin_release with the one from bin_debug.  It showed "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://localhost:9443/myApp/resources/osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swf". It did not take the swz. But tried to load the swf file for the framework. The swf files were not deployed since it is not there in the bin_release folder. When i copied all the swf files for the framework from the bin_debug to the server, it worked.

I found a post about this.
[How do I recompile Flex 4 Framework RSLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221311/how-do-i-recompile-flex-4-framework-rsls)

When will flash player look for unsigned RSL? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Manoj

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by framework caching?  It's just the normal caching in the browser.  There shouldn't be any problems with using a VPN unless not all your framework files are available in your web directory.

Comment: Framework caching is a technique which isolates all the flex framework related files from the application and caches into the flash player's cache(Not the browser cache).